# How do I have level 13 out of 12 friendship with my wife?

Tags: stardew-valley

While talking with my wife recently, the friendship level pop-up in the dialogue box shows we have level "13/12":
[image: 13/12 friendship]
This seems peculiar, since only 12 hearts out of a maximum of 12 show in the social tab:
[image: 12 hearts in social tab]
Furthermore, on the wiki ([here](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Friendship) and [here](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Marriage)), the maximum friendship level is stated to be 12 for a spouse. From the second link (emphasis mine):

> Once a villager has been married, they will move into the farmhouse. They will have a **maximum of 12 hearts** instead of 10 [...]

**How is this possible that the friendship level is above 12, which appears to be the maximum?**

Comment: Asking for developer information is off-topic.  In game explanation, we can do, or some sort of bug explanation, but wanting dev info makes it fall squarely into developer intent.

Comment: I realise asking for information only the developers would know is off-topic. What I mean is is there any information on this that we do know, ie not developer intent.

Comment: Asking directly for developer information is the same thing as developer intent; it requires the developer to have said something in order to answer the question.  Focus on the issue itself, instead of how you want answerers to answer it.

Comment: Alright. If I edit out "Is there any information from on this (from the developers perhaps)?" would the question be more squarely on-topic?

Comment: Perhaps changing the last paragraph to something like, "How is this possible?", would make it much better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in fact intended.

As DanmakuGrazer said, by increasing your relationship with your spouse, it will eventually reach 13 hearts. When this happens, the relationship becomes "capped" like every other relationship: it won't naturally decay. (It can still decrease due to actions such as the character witnessing you digging through trash, or if you give gifts to bachelor/ettes while married.)

Getting your spouse's relationship to 13 is a requirement for

> getting a stardrop. More accurately, once your spouse is at 13.5/12 hearts, you'll receive the stardrop. (H/T @Pathoschild.)

In fact, in the past, instead of being represented as 13/12, this would be shown

> as a stardrop icon.

Comment: Based on the code, that happens the moment you reach 13.5 hearts internally. There's no probability involved. :)

Comment: @Pathoschild Huh, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the developer, ConcernedApe, has not spoken on this matter, we have no way of knowing whether it's intended or a bug.

---

Now that the question has been changed, I'm afraid the answer is still pretty boring: it just happens. Keep giving gifts and paying attention to your spouse, and friendship will (always?) reach 13 hearts out of 12.